# Trouble with returning data consistently after performing SQL stored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, windows-server-2008-r2

all,

i have been lurking on stackoverflow for a few years now, always able to find the help needed to resolve the issue at hand. however, this time, i needed to create my first question as i was unable to find questions that hit on the same issue i am encountering.

i have been stumped for over a week and am getting into hot water at work because i already blew my estimated date. i put myself at your mercy in the hopes that you may help me with my coding headache.

i am able to return data from executing a stored procedure through PHP on a SQL 2008 server on a VM (running windows 2008 r2) where i pass in one parameter.

that parameter has a total of eleven (11) choices. whenever i pass in one (1) of those choices, expected data is returned.

however, whenever i use any of the other choices, no data is returned (and with my current code, no errors are returned either).

there are 11 choices of **$application_selected** to pass into the stored procedure and only one (1) of those choices returns data. none of the others return data or errors.

here is my entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>data</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//connection information
$servername = "192.168.1.104";
$username = "sa";
$password = "*";
$database = "*";

$connection_info = array( "Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $servername, $connection_info);

if($conn===FALSE) die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
else echo "<font color=\"blue\">DB Connected.</font><br>";
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$application_selected = "param1";
$sql_cmd = "EXECUTE GetApprover '$application_selected'";

$execute_this = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql_cmd);
$application_proc = sqlsrv_execute($execute_this);

if($application_proc===FALSE) die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); //execute failed; die and display errors

else echo "<font color=\"blue\">DB data retrieved.</font><br><br>";

$row_apps = "";
$count = 0;
echo "<font color=\"blue\">Attempting data output via loop</font><br><br>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// output data
//echo var_dump($execute_this)."<br><br>";
echo "<font color=\"blue\">Application selected = </font>\"".$application_selected."<font color=\"blue\">\" - data pulled &#9660;</font><br><br>";
while(($row_apps = sqlsrv_fetch_array($execute_this)) && (sqlsrv_fetch_array($execute_this) <> FALSE)) { //while var has data
if (!isset($row_apps)) die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
$count += 1;
echo $row_apps['ApplicationName']." - ".$row_apps['ApproverCode']." - ".$row_apps['ApproverDesc']." - ".$row_apps['FullName']." - ".$row_apps['Email']." - ".$row_apps['UserId']."<br>";
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

echo "<br><font color=\"blue\">&#9650; Data displayed.";
echo "<br><br><font color=\"blue\">There were [<font color=\"red\"><b>$count</b></font>] rows returned.<br><br><br>";

echo "<br>\$servername = ";
echo var_dump($servername)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$username = ";
echo var_dump($username)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$password = ";
echo var_dump($password)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$database = ";
echo var_dump($database)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$connection_info = ";
echo var_dump($connection_info)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$conn = ";
echo var_dump($conn)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$application_selected = ";
echo var_dump($application_selected)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$sql_cmd = ";
echo var_dump($sql_cmd)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$execute_this = ";
echo var_dump($execute_this)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$application_proc = ";
echo var_dump($application_proc)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$row_apps = ";
echo var_dump($row_apps)."<br>";
echo "<br>\$count = ";
echo var_dump($count)."<br>";

echo "<br><br><br>";
sqlsrv_close($conn);
echo "<br>DB Connection closed.</font><br><br><br>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: basic debugging: what happens if you try to run the sproc manually through MSSMS, with each of those choices?

Comment: Marc B - thank you for commenting. i am working with a dba that may or may not be soft in this sort of thing. however, whenever he runs the sproc in his environment, he seems to get back all the data correctly/as expected.

Comment: make sure things are entirely consistent, including logging into MSSMS with the same id you're using in the php code. doesn't mean much if the dba logs in with `sa`-level privileges and you're running under a restricted account.

Comment: can you provide examples of the choices that fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems my preliminary suspicions (although i had no tangible proof of such) of some sort of db issue was the culprit after pushing my dba (also my director) with some test results from added debug code [like var_dump()/print_r()]. his reply to the issue that caused it all was as follows:

"i don't know what happened but i copied the table content from my dev environment to your dev environment and now things work."

i'm sorry to trouble you all with my issue. i am grateful that Marc B and Raad answered my plea for help so quickly and i really hope this question helps someone in the future.